# Separate Join clause in a Composite Index

Tags: mysql, composite-index

Would having a Composite Index be beneficial for something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM a INNER JOIN b ON(a.id=b.id)
                INNER JOIN c ON(a.bar=c.id)
                INNER JOIN d ON(a.foo=d.id)
```

Index would be:

```
(a.id, a.bar, a.foo)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the leading edge of the index would be used (`a.id`), so only the `INNER JOIN` to `b` would benefit from the index... so the additional columns in the index (`a.bar` and `a.foo`) are not beneficial in the sample query posted.

[From the MySql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html):

> MySQL cannot use the index to perform lookups if the columns do not
>   form a leftmost prefix of the index. Suppose that you have the `SELECT`
>   statements shown here:
>
> ```
> SELECT * 
> FROM tbl_name 
> WHERE col1=val1; 
>
> SELECT * 
> FROM tbl_name 
> WHERE col1=val1 AND col2=val2;
>
> SELECT * 
> FROM tbl_name 
> WHERE col2=val2; 
>
> SELECT * 
> FROM tbl_name 
> WHERE col2=val2 AND col3=val3;
> ```
>
> If an index exists on `(col1, col2, col3)`,
>   only the first two queries use the index. The third and fourth queries
>   do involve indexed columns, but `(col2)` and `(col2, col3)` are not
>   leftmost prefixes of `(col1, col2, col3)`.

Answer (score 1):

When `JOINing` (that is, `INNER JOIN`, not `LEFT JOIN`), the Optimizer will pick *any* of the tables as the "first" table.  Then it will use the `ON` clause to move on to the next table and do a "NLJ" (Nested Loop Join) to reach into that second table.  Etc.

*Usually*, when there is a `WHERE` clause (or certain other things), that will determine which table is "first".  Without that, the Optimizer will *usually* pick the smallest table.

Given a `WHERE` clause on one of the tables, it will look for the 'best' `INDEX` to use.  Such an index is likely to have one or more columns involved in the `WHERE` clause.  Two indexes will not (with rare exceptions) be used at the same time for a single table.

When moving on to the 'next' table, *probably* an index on the column(s) in the `ON` clause determines the optimal index.  Note that if you have `ON a.x=b.x AND a.y=b.y`, then the composite `INDEX(x,y)` (either order) is desirable.

Back to the case of not deciding on which table to "start" with...  The Optimizer will try a variety of orders for the table.  With each different ordering, there is a different set of indexes.

For this

```
     FROM a 
     INNER JOIN b ON(a.id=b.id)
     INNER JOIN c ON(a.bar=c.id)
     INNER JOIN d ON(a.foo=d.id)
```

These are optimal, but we can't necessarily predict which will be used:

```
a:  (id)  -- if coming from b
a:  (bar) -- if coming from c
a:  (foo) -- if coming from d
b:  (id)  -- if coming from b 
c:  (id)  -- if coming from a
d:  (id)  -- if coming from a
```

Note: You probably already have `PRIMARY KEY(id)` in each of the tables, so there is no need to add `INDEX(id)`.

You said `SELECT *`, meaning you wanted all the columns from all four tables.  If that is not really the case, we can discuss another optimization:  "covering indexes".

More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql