# Could you explain aspect of using Composite MySQL INDEX for multiple INNER JOIN?

Tags: mysql, database, join, indexing, compound-index

**The query is**

```
SELECT v.value
FROM products
         JOIN products_attributes_options pao
              ON 1 = 1
                  AND products.id = pao.product_id
         JOIN attributes_options ao
              ON 1 = 1
                  AND pao.attribute_option_id = ao.id
                  AND attribute_id = 12
         JOIN attributes_options_values aov
              ON
                      1 = 1
                      AND ao.id = aov.attribute_option_id
         JOIN `values` v
              ON
                      1 = 1
                      AND aov.value_id = v.id

         JOIN values_words vw_1
              ON
                      1 = 1
                      AND v.id = vw_1.value_id
         JOIN values_words vw_2
              ON
                      1 = 1
                      AND v.id = vw_2.value_id

         JOIN words w_1
              ON
                      1 = 1
                      AND vw_1.word_id = w_1.id
                      AND w_1.value LIKE '%a%'
         JOIN words w_2
              ON
                      1 = 1
                      AND vw_2.word_id = w_2.id
                      AND w_2.value LIKE '%a%'

GROUP BY v.id, v.value
ORDER BY v.id, v.value
```

**For this part of query**

```
JOIN products_attributes_options pao
     ON 1 = 1
        AND products.id = pao.product_id
JOIN attributes_options ao
     ON 1 = 1
        AND pao.attribute_option_id = ao.id
        AND attribute_id = 12
```

**I have composite indexes**

```
ix_aov_p (attribute_option_id, product_id)
ix_p_aov (product_id, attribute_option_id)
```

Via `EXPLAIN` my query I have seen - two of them could be possible keys.
But I thought only `ix_aov_p` is enough.

Could you explain how do composite indexes work for these cases?
Do I need two indexes or only one index? Which of them I need to use?
`ix_aov_p` or `ix_p_aov`

I have researched similar question, but there is not enough explanation for understanding - what happens?

[Separate Join clause in a Composite Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13165352/separate-join-clause-in-a-composite-index) - similar question - accepted answer didn't explain enough what happens and why composite INDEX doesn't work.

Glad to explanation what happens from the INDEX side with these JOINs for understanding composite INDEXes using in this case.

---

DB dump
Tables to use - DUMP (structure)

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `attributes_options`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `attributes_options`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `attributes_options` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `attribute_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `option_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `attributes_options`
--

LOCK TABLES `attributes_options` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `attributes_options` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `attributes_options` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `attributes_options_values`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `attributes_options_values`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `attributes_options_values` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `attribute_option_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `attributes_options_values`
--

LOCK TABLES `attributes_options_values` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `attributes_options_values` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `attributes_options_values` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `products`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `products`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `products`
--

LOCK TABLES `products` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `products` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `products` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `products_attributes_options`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `products_attributes_options`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `products_attributes_options` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `attribute_option_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ix_p_aov` (`product_id`,`attribute_option_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ix_aov_p` (`attribute_option_id`,`product_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `products_attributes_options`
--

LOCK TABLES `products_attributes_options` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `products_attributes_options` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `products_attributes_options` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `values`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `values`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `values` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` varchar(190) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `values`
--

LOCK TABLES `values` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `values` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `values` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `values_words`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `values_words`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `values_words` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `word_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `values_words`
--

LOCK TABLES `values_words` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `values_words` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `values_words` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `words`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `words`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `words` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(190) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `words`
--

LOCK TABLES `words` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `words` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `words` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;
```

[image: Tables visualization]

Comment: Please rewrite the query so that the `ON` clauses specify how tables are _related_ and the `WHERE` clause does the filtering.  You seem to have the filtering scattered in the `ON` clauses.  Also, de-clutter it by removing the `1=1 AND`.  Is `id` the `PRIMARY KEY` of each table?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: I added an Answer to the Question you linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is much too normalized.

It is good to normalize `product` with `product_id` if the `Products` table has lots of info -- name, size, etc.  But all I see is `name`.  So get rid of `product_id` and `Products` and just have a column `product_name`.

After you have done that, identify the many:many mapping tables.  They need no `id`, but just two columns, each being either an id or a value.  See this for advice on the optimal composite indexes for such tables:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

> But I thought only ix_aov_p is enough.

That provides an efficient way for "given an aov, find the p values".  In other situations, you need the opposite order.  Composite indexes are ordered.  In the case of a mapping table like that, the "given" must come first.

In some other situations the ordering is important:

```
WHERE b > 4 AND a = 8
```

needs `INDEX(a, b)` *in that order*.  It can quickly get to all the entries for a=8 and b=4, them scan forward until a>8.  Think about searching for lastname='James' and firstname LIKE 'R%'.

Meanwhile, either order of `INDEX(a,b)` is fine for

```
WHERE b = 4 AND a = 8
```

More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql